# Xcode 7 swift playground - missing Timeline slider window

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

I can't see the timeline slider in my Xcode 7 playground. I created a new default "hello world" project, following the instruction in the "About Playgrounds" help topic, and neither the "Timeline slider" nor the "Time field" window appears at the bottom of the playground.

[image]

I've tried the various view options under the View menu and searched the help and www, no obvious answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you open the Project settings (right hand panel) you can see two options in the Playground Settings section (under the platform choice dropdown).

One is "Render documentation" which changes the format of the comments in the playground so it looks more like a book, or a web page with formatted code samples.

The second is "Show Timeline" which will put the slider back on the window.

[image]